# How to pull from GitHub using token

Tags: git, github

Until today I've been using GitHub Desktop to navigate git and GitHub. However, I decided this morning to attempt some tasks from the terminal on my Mac. I started with navigating to my repo folder and then running `git pull`. I was kindly referred to [this page](https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/) explaining about personal tokens etc etc.

I duly created a token and then used homebrew to install `gh` and run `gh auth login`. Everything went swimmingly and I'm now logged onto GitHub.

However, how do I now execute my pull? I've tried `git pull` again but that asks me for my username and password again and I go round in a big circle to be referred to the link above :( I've had a look at `gh -help` but I couldn't see a pull command...

- Git: 2.15
- MacOS: 12.1

Comment: I guess you are supposed to use the token instead of the password, if you want git to save your password/token run `git config --global credential.helper store`

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Do I need to put something on the end of that line? Just ran it and nothing happened...

Comment: Git on macOS encourages you (well, macOS itself encourages you, and Git can work with that) to store keys—passwords, tokens, and other such stuff—in the macOS "keychain". This isn't managed *by* Git at all. Git then just goes and asks the OS nicely for the right key, and if it is authorized (because it's running as something you ran) it gets that key and Git then passes it on to GitHub.

Comment: To add, update, or remove a key from the OS X Keychain, see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/updating-credentials-from-the-macos-keychain

Comment: Note that you don't *have* to use the keychain at all. You can use the klunky stuff distributed *with* Git, or use ssh. But OS X Keychain is all fancy and shiny and a lot of people like that stuff.  Note that GItHub themselves recommend "Git Credential Manager", which is a Microsoft product. The suspicious-minded might also note that this occurred after Microsoft bought GitHub.  Personally I like ssh myself....